# Input masking text box in mobile website form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, masking

I have a requirement where i need to apply input masking to text boxes in a form used in mobile website.

For example : I have the below form used in my mobile website where the phone no# need to be masked as per the example text given in the label. I tries using a no of jquery plugins to get this working , but i found the working perfectly in web but fails to run in mobile browsers.

[image]

I read online in one of the comment saying the mobile browsers does not rely on the keypress and keydown event. Is that true ?

I tried using my own code to achieve the solution (code below)

```
    function formatPhone(e, node) {
    var keycode =  e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(keycode == 8){ // backspace
        return false;
    }
    if(keycode == 46){ // delete
        return false;
    } 
    var input = $(node).val();
    input = input.replace(/-/g, '');
    var areaCode = input.substring(0, 3);
    var exchange = input.substring(3, 6);
    var tail = input.substring(6);          
    $(node).val(areaCode + "-" + exchange + "-" + tail);                            

}
 $('#${PRE_ID}Phone').keyup(function (e) { formatPhone(e, this); });
```

The above code works in web browser, but when it comes to mobile the first 3 digits works correctly, but the 4th and 5th digit swap and the sequence of number always fails. And also when you delete the no, not all the numbers get removed.

Do we have any plugin from jquery or any code snippet which does this job ?

**Below are some of the plugins which i tried in mobile default browsers(and failed) for S2,S3,iPhone**

mask | jQuery Plugin Registry
http://andr-04.github.io/inputmask-multi/en.html
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxmaskedinput/index.htm
http://mavrin.github.io/maskInput/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This works for me even on Mobile:

$("#phoneInput").jqxMaskedInput({ width: 250, height: 25, mask: '-###-###-####'});

I've used it with IPhone and Nexus.

Comment: The concern is that this plugin is payed and it comes in a bundle of several features which i dont need. The only featurei need is the input mask.